# How to use boolean features to classify, penalising number of features

Tags: classification, cart

I have a set of boolean features (n=~2k) to predict a categorical outcome. I have been using decision trees via sklearn successfully.

However, for unseen data, there is a cost to assay each feature, and for this cost we obtain data across all observations. A decision tree can therefore be inefficient, as feature 1 can separate Class A immediately, but we have already paid the cost of assaying features 2+ on class A already.

I am looking for a method that somehow takes this into account, where we can minimise the total number of features used rather than the tree depth.

Hope I have made myself clear here- thanks in advance!